# Apache Camel with org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:4.4.1 ?

Tags: java, apache, http, apache-camel

Can HTTP4 component in apache camel can be configured to use
'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:4.4.1' to execute requests ?

As of now the version 2.15.2 is not having this dependency ?

TIA

Comment: Have you already tried to exclude all `httpclient:4.3.6` references from `camel-http4` and then add `httpclient:4.4.1` and related stuff manually?

Comment: @Roman : No not httpClient latest version. 
I wanted to see if i can use "httpclient-cache:4.4.1" which supports caching http requests at Client level using memcached.

Comment: I'm not sure if the Http4Component already supports this feature, but I think you can initialize a custom HttpClient using the cache and set/inject that into the Http4Component.